# Mesh surface using image textures need to be unwarped everytime when assigned or changed in cycles

Tags: texturing, image

I'm having an issue with image textures. Everytime i change the picture or texture coordinate or anything connected to the image texture, i need to unwarp the mesh to make the changes displayed on render. It is kinda ennoying when rendering a whole scene with animation.

Do you guys know how to fix that?

[edited]

Here in the first door's window, We can see the original texture image

[image]

In this picture, i have copied the first door and put it at the end of the room, and the image texture displayed like this.

[image]

As you can see, the image Texture is displayed wrong (zoomed or something) and i have to unwarp the upper bart of the door to get the the proper display(like the yellow door).

Comment: Is this happening in all of your files? Did you tried with the factory default scene? Could you show a picture/video of your issue?

Comment: it happened on different projects too.

Comment: I have fixed it temporary until i find a better solution, if you guys got anything better please share with me. Well, i placed a simple plane with my texture on it in the background door, i removed the window faces so I can see the background plane behind it,